# Add jsonb property of type boolean

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to add a property to an existing `jsonb` column (column "data").

I want have my `jsonb` document to log like this

```json
{
  // ... existing properties
  "Filed": false // new property
}
```

I tried

```
UPDATE "doc" SET "data" = jsonb_set("data"::jsonb, 'Filed', false, true)
```

I get this error:

```
[42883] ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, boolean, boolean) does not exist 
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. 
You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 46
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
jsonb_set("data"::jsonb, '{Filed}', 'false', TRUE)
```

The second parameter is an array denoting the path to the appropriate key, and `'false'` is the string representation of a JSON boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Better use the `||` operator.

```sql
UPDATE "doc" SET "data" = "data" || '{"Filed": false}';
```

This one is equivalent but more suitable for parameterization:

```sql
UPDATE "doc" SET "data" = "data" || jsonb_build_object('Filed', false);
```